# Saying in Excel: IF this is true, then show me the cell two below

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Hy there,

i am trying to create an automatic invoice and probably i am making my life much more complicated than i should.

here is my problem... i have these tables (short version)
Name
Street
Place

this i have of a variety of guests. on the invoice of the guest i want to just write the name and it automatically finds the adress and place of the specific guest in my tables.

in  my excel file i am writing basically the name of the guest, in the street name i tried it through IF this name, vlookup in this table array. unfortunatly i dont know how i can say that when you find that name use this persons adress, which is below his name... at least i couldnt manage that it shows the correct adress if the person i typed in, just that it shows the name again or the adress of the first person in the list.

hope it is half way clear and someone has an easy solution for me :)

Comment: Please share the IF/VLOOKUP formula you are using so we can help you resolve it.

Comment: The formula would be as follow (the cells are just named randomly) if(A1=A2,vlookup(A1,B1:B4),1,false),false)         best would be if the table array could be more columns, so i assume macth as mentioned by bensheperd would be more of help here. trying to work that out at that mment with match and offset combined

Comment: Is your data like this - (row) (1)name (2)street (3)place (4)name2 (5)street2 (6)place2 ?

Comment: hey, i could arrange it under each other, but so far it is as follows:  column 1 Row1 name column 1 Row2 street column 1 Row3 place (5 timesbelow each other with empty spaces in between)and than in column 4 the next guests, same way as before

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `index match` that is offset by the number of rows (1 here) like -

`=INDEX($D$1:$D$6,MATCH(A1,$D$1:$D$6,0)+1)`

[image]

Comment: this works perfectly :) thank you so much... saves me from typing hundreds of adress manually :)

Answer (score 0):

Some combination of `MATCH` (to find the row you're looking for) and `OFFSET` should do the trick. That should give you a more generalised version of the `VLOOKUP` that you're currently using.

Comment: Hy Benshepherd, thanks for the help so far. unfortunatly i dont get the offset work as i want. cyrrently i have offset(Match(NameCell,A38:N86),0),1,0,1,1)   it tells me the formula is not valid. is it possible to use the match as search fo the offset?

Answer (score 0):

You've not explained how the data is arranged, so I can not be sure if this will be correct, but I believe your `VLOOKUP` syntax is wrong within the `IF` statement.

Try this;

```
=IF(A1=A2,VLOOKUP(A1,B1:B4,1,false),"false")
```

This will check if `A1` is equal to `A2`. If it is it will look up an exact match of the value of `A1` in the range of `B1:B4`, then return the result of the first column. In the case where the `IF` finds `A1` is not equal to `A2`, it will return the text "false".

Here is a great tutorial on [vlookup(), match() and offset() – explained in plain english [spreadcheats]](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/11/19/vlookup-match-and-offset-explained-in-plain-english-spreadcheats/).

Comment: Hey CharlieRB, this is exactly what it does... just that i do not want to display the value in the cell or next to the cell found but the ones below. and it would be necessary that this cell filled in is always from the found value... it is arranged in my file as mentioned int he starting post comments... ( column 1 Row1 name column 1 Row2 street column 1 Row3 place (5 timesbelow each other with empty spaces in between)and than in column 4 the next guests, same way as before

Comment: Now that we know how the data is laid out, VLOOKUP is not useful for you. @raystafarian has a great answer for you above.